# Remove Curved lines from captcha image open cv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tesseract

I am trying to bypass captcha images for a website and need almost 85% accuracy and I have been at it for the last week, it looks seemingly impossible now. Currently I get just 40% accuracy. Please help. I am sharing my code and some image samples below:

The images always have numbers but the issue is with the lines. I am not able to deal with the lines as the gradient is same as the numbers.

[image: Captcha2]

[image: captcha4captcha5captcha6]

```
    # enable the following if loading tesseract from local server
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

    # reading image using opencv
    image = cv2.imread('C:\\images\\ipcaptcha\\asys.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Apply Threshold
    # Dilate and Erode
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (kernel, kernel), 0)
    ret, thresh_img = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    image = cv2.dilate(image, np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8))
    image = cv2.erode(image, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))

    scale_percent = 300
    width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)

    image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    h = image.shape[0]
    w = image.shape[1]

    # configuring parameters for tesseract
    custom_config = r'--psm 8 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
    # now feeding image to tesseract
    details = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DICT, config=custom_config, lang='eng')
    total_boxes = len(details['text'])
    for sequence_number in range(total_boxes):
        if int(details['conf'][sequence_number]) > 30:
            (x, y, w, h) = (
                details['left'][sequence_number], details['top'][sequence_number], details['width'][sequence_number],
                details['height'][sequence_number])
            threshold_img = cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # get the details read by tesseract
    show_text = details['text']
    final1 = []
    for i in show_text:
        if i is not '' and len(i) > 1:
            for j in i:
                if j.isdigit():
                    final1.append(j)
    final1 = ''.join(final1)
    final = final1
    
    if len(final1) > 6:
        final = list(final1)
        final.pop(0)
        final = "".join(final)

    cv2.imshow('captured text', image)
    # Maintain output window until user presses a key
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    # Destroying present windows on screen
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print(final)
    print("The End")
```

Comment: The logic against to captcha existence.

Comment: I suggest that this activity is unethical. Attempting to subvert the CAPTCHA protection shows a lack of respect for the owner of the server, whether they are doing it to protect their bandwidth or their business